# Diagnostic checking of GARCH model with Student-$t$ errors

Tags: time-series, garch

I used R to fit a GARCH model with Student-$t$ distribution to a financial time series.

How should I check for independence of the standardized Student-$t$ errors? Is it correct to run the usual Jarque-Bera test?

Could you provide me with any reference on how to perform diagnostic checking on GARCH models with Student-$t$ distribution?

Comment: Have I answered your question? You have neither commented on it nor accepted/upvoted.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I have been away from CV for a while. Your answer made my revise my books more carefully. I implicity had assumed something wrong while studying the concept of independence. Anyway, again thank you for clarifing my doubts. As you may have already understood, I am still studying the topic of ARMA and GARCH modelling and do not have the same knowledge and capacity of critical thinking as a professional researcher. So step-by-step post-by-post CV is providing me extremely useful answers to my doubts :)

Comment: The two books I am studying and using for implementation of my ARMA and GARCH modelling exercise are: Tsay R.S. (2013), An Introduction to Analysis of Financial Data with R, Wiley. and J.D. Cryer and K. Chan (2008), Time Series Analysis with Applications in R, Springer.

Comment: Nice to hear that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I check for independence of the standardized Student-T errors? Is it correct to run the usual Jarque Bera Test?

You cannot check the independence of a time series *directly*, but you can examine whether *certain forms* of dependence are present and hopefully reject those.
A GARCH model focuses on the conditional variance; cond. variance depends on cond. mean. Therefore, it would be reasonable to look for dependence in the first two moments.

- Ljung-Box and/or Breusch-Pagan tests could probably be applied on standardized residuals (std. res.) from the GARCH model to look for dependence in the cond. mean (autocorrelations). The Ljung-Box test is often used in practice. However, I am not sure if these tests have the regular null distributions when applied to std. res. from a GARCH model rather than raw data or residuals from a conditional mean model. (This also means the $p$-values for the Ljung-Box and weighted Ljung-Box tests reported by default for GARCH models in the "rugarch" package in R may be invalid.)
- Li-Mak test is designed for examining presence of ARCH patterns in std. res. from a GARCH model. (Meanwhile, the more popular approaches of applying the ARCH-LM test on std. res. or the Ljung-Box test on squared std. res. are unjustified as the test statistics do not have the standard null distributions which were derived for raw data rather than std. res. This also means the $p$-values for the ARCH-LM test reported by default for GARCH models in the "rugarch" package in R are invalid.)

Since the Jarque-Bera test assesses *normality* (not some form of dependence), it does not make sense to use it for dependence testing.

> Could you provide me with any reference on how to perform diagnostics checking on GARCH models with Student-T distribution?

Besides the remarks above, you could test whether the std. res. have a Student-$t$ distribution, because that is a modelling assumption you have made when fitting the model. For that you could do a one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test against the Student-$t$ distribution with the estimated degrees of freedom.